# C++ changing class variable inside class method

Tags: c++

Class definition:

```
    class videoPlay {
public:
    VideoCapture video;
    int cannyThreshold;
    int houghThreshold;
    int clickX;
    int clickY;
    int sB;
    int clickRadius;
    bool playVideo;
    bool edgeDetection;
    Mat selectedBall;
    Mat frame;
    Mat origFrame;
    vector<Vec3f> houghCircles;

    videoPlay( VideoCapture video ) : video(video) {}
    void nextFrame();
    void houghTransform();
    void detectEdges();
    void drawFrame();
    void mouseActionListener(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata);
    void selectBall();
    void addLabel(int num);
};
```

The two methods

```
void videoPlay::selectBall( ) {
    frame = origFrame.clone();
    for(int i = 0; i < houghCircles.size(); i++) {
        int x = houghCircles[i][0];
        int y = houghCircles[i][1];
        int radius = cvRound(houghCircles[i][2]);

        float circleEq = pow(clickX - x, 2) + pow(clickY - y, 2);
        Point center(cvRound(x), cvRound(y));

        if(circleEq <= pow(radius, 2)) {
            circle(frame, center, radius, Scalar(255, 0, 255), 4, 8, 0);
            sB = i;
            cout << sB << " - " << i << endl;
        } else {
            circle(frame, center, radius, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0);
        }
    }
}

void videoPlay::addLabel(int num) {
    cout << sB << endl;
    int x = (int)houghCircles[sB][0];
    int y = (int)houghCircles[sB][1];
    putText(frame, "1", Point(x, y), 1, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 0), 1, 8, 0);
}
```

I call `videoplayobject.selectBall()` in a `mouseclick` call back. It then sets `sB` to the ball (if any) that the mouse pointer is inside. Then I press <kbd>1</kbd> on the keyboard and inside a `switch statement` after a waitkey `addLabel` method is called. It should use `sB` to index into the `houghCircles` vector at the number set in `selectBall`, but instead it is going back to the original value that `sB` is instantiated to. For some reason `sB` is not properly being set inside `selectBall()`

`sB` is set to say 2 in the `selectBall` method, but when `addLabel` comes to use `sB` to index into a vector then `sB` doesn't == what it was set to in `selectBall`. Am I doing something very stupid?

Many thanks.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong in the posted code. Perhaps you can post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: are you calling the two methods on the same `videoPlay` instance ?

Comment: I am Sander. I'm really stumped, it's driving me mad!

Comment: if you can't accurately give us what it is that you want to do or clarify this segment of code's purpose, I am afraid we can not help you.

Comment: I call videoplayobject.selectBall() in a mouseclick call back. It then sets sB to the ball (if any) that the mouse pointer is inside. Then I press "1" on the keyboard and inside a switch statement after a waitkey addLabel method is called. It should use sB to index into the houghCircles vector at the number set in selectBall, but instead it is going back to the original value that sB is instatiated to. For some reason sB is not properly being set inside selectBall()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check that the two callbacks are using the same instance of `videoPlay`. You can do it e.g. like this within the two methods:

```
cout << "this = '" << this << "'" << endl;
```

(Sorry I think this would be better as a comment, but I don't have enough rep. yet to add comments...)

Comment: It appears to be that my mouseCallback isn't using the right instance of videoPlay. Thank you very much for your help! I'd +rep if I could.